# How to use grep on column?

Tags: grep, columns

I want to apply grep on particular column in column command.

myfile.txt

```
3,ST,ST01,3,3,856
3,ST,ST02,4,9,0234
6,N1,N101,2,3,ST
6,N1,N102,1,60,Comcast
6,N1,N103,1,2,92
```

My Command:

```
column -s, -t < myfile.txt | grep -w "ST"
```

Here I want to only grep the pattern ST in 2nd column. How to do this ?

**Expected Result:**

```
3       ST            ST01              3            3            856
3       ST            ST02              4            9            0234
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Without doing some fancy RegEx where you count commas, you're better off using `awk` for this problem.

```
awk -F, '$2=="ST"'
```

- The `-F,` parameter specifies the delimiter, which is set to a comma for your data.
- `$2` refers to the second column, which is what you want to match on.
- `"ST"` is the value you want to match.

Comment: How to pass variable instead of ST here ?

Comment: @RajagopalSubramanian a shell variable? If so, you can use `-v` parameter and pass in variables, but if it's an environment variable it's even easier because you can use `ENVIRON["TERM"]` for your variable in the awk expression itself.

Comment: yes. A shell variable

Comment: @RajagopalSubramanian yes, you should find it if you search. I also updated my comment above. However, this was not part of the question so it is not reflected in my answer.

Comment: very sorry guys.

Comment: $ man awk, and look at the options

Comment: Can the string be regex, too?

Comment: How are you passing a variable, this is not working:
awk -F, -v a=$2 'a=="ST"'

Comment: @user1261558 There is no variable being passed. `$2` refers to the second column in the input. What you wrote is not what I provided in my answer. I don't know what you're trying to do.

Comment: I interpreted it wrongly, sorry.

Answer (score 5):

Get `ST` in column 2 (`-E` and `{1}` can be omitted here):

```
grep -E '^([^,]*,){1}ST[^,]*' file
```

Output:

```
3  ST  ST01  3  3  856
3  ST  ST02  4  9  0234
```

Get `ST` in column 6:

```
grep -E '^([^,]*,){5}ST[^,]*' file | column -s, -t
```

Output:

```
6  N1  N101  2  3  ST
```

Answer (score 0):

By using `awk` we can select required column,

```
column -s, -t < myfile.txt | awk '$2 == "ST"'
```

If shell variable used,

```
seg="ST"
column -s, -t < $ST_FILE | awk -v var="$seg" '($2 == var)'
```